# DisplayImage.cpp errors Using OpenCV with gcc and CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc

I've had issues in compiling DisplayImage.cpp, I've followed the tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage) and to create a cmake file and generate executables, however, when I was compiling the problem with make it displays the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
_main in DisplayImage.cpp.o
"cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
_main in DisplayImage.cpp.o
"cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
_main in DisplayImage.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [DisplayImage] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am running MacOS could anyone please help!

Thanks

Comment: i am having this problem too.

Comment: add set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-mmacosx-version-min=10.7") to your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thank you! This line of code was the answer for more than 2 hours searching!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
```

to the top of DisplayImage.cpp code. Then compile and execute again.
Hope it works! I just tried and verified it myself now.